# How to remove duplicate line in a list when its values are from dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

So there is something I have to do in this format but couldn't figure out why TRADE repeats whenever I show the results at the end. I'd like to retain the TRADE row that it's meant to have by removing the duplicates. So the code looks like this:

```
def computeTable():

   cols = ['NAME', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']

   table_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
   table_list = []

   insert_sell = {}
   insert_high = {}
   insert_buy = {} 
   insert_low = {}

   for col in cols:
      if(col == 'NAME'):
         insert_sell = 'SELL'
         insert_high = 'TRADE'
         insert_buy = 'BUY'  
         insert_low = 'TRADE'
      else:
         insert_sell = 1
         insert_high = 2
         insert_buy = 3 
         insert_low = 4

   table_list.append(insert_sell)
   table_list.append(insert_high)
   table_list.append(insert_buy)
   table_list.append(insert_low)

   return pd.DataFrame(table_list)
```

```
compute_table = computeTable()
compute_table = compute_table.fillna(0)
```

```
table2 = ['SELL', 'TRADE', 'BUY', 'TRADE']

table_list2 = []

for row in table2:
   rowFromTable = compute_table.loc[compute_table['NAME'] == row.reset_index()
   table_list2.append(rowFromTable)

table_list2
```

But the results for TRADE duplicates like this:

```
[    index NAME Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
   0   0   SELL 1  1  1  1
   0   1   TRADE 2 2  2  2
   *1   3   TRADE 4 4  4  4*
   0   2   BUY  3  3  3  3
   *0   1   TRADE 2 2  2  2*
   1   3   TRADE 4 4  4  4   ]
```

I want to remove the lines with asterisks. I would like to know how with some explanations since I'm still fairly new to Python and pandas.

Edit: I run this in Jupyter Notebook so it the format follows how it is divided in my file.

Comment: Lets look at `insert_sell`. It is  declared as dict: `insert_sell = {}` and later a string or int is assigned to it. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Not really. But I wanted to eventually call a value from the excel table so I just used numbers for now to simplify this question.